# PUT request returning a 400 Bad Request Error

Tags: rest, jquery, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

I am doing a PUT request to RESTfull service which changes password of a user. For the time being I have just hardcoded values of new and old password in my AJAX test my service. However it is giving me a 400 error.

**AJAX call**

```
$.ajax({
        type: "PUT",
        url: "api/teachers/"+user,
       data: {"old":"123","new":"qwe"},
       contentType: "application/json",
        success: function(data,status) 
        {
            datax = data;
            alert(data+status);
            ko.applyBindings(new AddMarkSheetKo(data));           
       },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert(XMLHttpRequest+textStatus+ errorThrown);
                  // error handler here
        }
      });
```

**Restful function:**

```
    @PUT
    @Path("/{name}")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response changePwd(@PathParam ("name")String name,@QueryParam ("old") String old, @QueryParam("new") String nw){
        System.out.println("entered function"+old+nw);
        Teacher t = DataAccessUtil.getByName(Teacher.class, name);
        if(t.getPassword().equals(old)){
            t.setPassword(nw);
            DataAccessUtil.update(t);
            return Response.ok().build();
        }
        else{
            return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity("Wrong password !!!").build();

        }
        //return reposnse;
    }
```

This information might be useful that on the console it prints

> entered functionnullnull

So it the restfull function is called however it is not receiving the query parameters.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you could replace the `@QueryParam` annotations with `@FormParam` ones to retrieve the 'new' and 'old' parameters of the PUT request. Then, you should remove the `@Consumes("application/json")` annotation and `contentType:application/json` from your server and browser side code, and finally replace the submitted data in JSON format into something like 'new=qwe&old=123'.

If you want to stay with a content in JSON format, you should probably map the incoming body with an entity (ie, a Java class annotated with JAXB annotations), so that the JAX-RS implementation you use could unmarshall the incoming JSON content into a Java object.

HTH.